# Javascript: Array is not working with Form

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes, palindrome

I currently am doing a a program that will show the primes and palindromic primes in a new window from a range a user inputs, here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> 9.25 Excercise </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        <!-- Begin
        var arrayLength = (parseInt(form.endNum.value))-(parseInt(form.startNum.value));
        var num=new Array(arrayLength);
        var number1=parseInt(form.startNum.value);

        for (var y=0; y<arrayLength; y++){
            num[y] = number1;
            number1++;
            }

        function calculate1(form) {
        var newWindow = window.open("","Test","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
        newWindow.document.write("Prime: <br> <br>");
        for (y=0; y<arrayLength; y++)
            if (num[y] == 1) {
                newWindow.document.write(num[y]);
            }
            for (var i=2;i<num[y];i++) {
                if (num[y] % i == 0) {
                    var prime="yes";
                    newWindow.document.write(num[y]);
                    break;
                }
            if (num[y] % i != 0) var prime="no";
            }
        }
        // End -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form name=form>
        This Program finds Prime numbers and Palindromic numbers between two integers.<br>
        Maximum range between the integers is 999.<br>
        <hr />
        Starting Value (>0):  <input type="number" name="startNum" min="1" max="99999"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Ending Value (<= 99999): <input type="number" name="endNum" min="1" max="99999"> <br>  <br>
        <input type=button value="Find Primes" onClick="calculate1(this.form)">
        <input type=button value="Find Palindromic Primes Only" onClick="calculate2(this.form)">
        <input type=button value="Find Both" onClick="calculate3(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
```

The problem I am having is that the numbers are not showing up in the window, and I don't know if its because of the array not working properly or I'm not writing to the window correctly. Currently, I can get it to show the number 1, but that is it. The data I want is also going into the array. The only issue is getting the prime numbers, other than 1 to show in the window, without breaking it. Note that this is a work in progress and currently I just need help showing the primes in the new window.

Edit: added more info about the problem

Comment: Maybe the comment at the beginning of your Javascript is affecting the behaviour of your code. That is not how you comment in Javascript

Comment: Check your browser console. You have at least 3 errors on sight. Like `parseInt(form.endNum.value)` where form is not defined and in the form tag you're missing the quotes. Also `calculate1()` should begin before `var arrayLenght`

Comment: What do you mean form is not defined?

Comment: @TheOniStixx you're using `form` in  `var arrayLength = (parseInt(form.endNum.value))` but the var form was never declared.

Comment: ok then, though now with all these changes, it will only show the number 1 if the range in 1 to anything, else it will still not show anything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://pastie.org/9952702) what you need..

**Note**:

- you may not access the `form` variable outside the function, since you pass the `this.form` as a parameter
- you may move the prime array below outside the function to skip recalculation when the `calculate_prime` called again
- it's preferable to use body's `onload` event or move the script before `</body>` to make sure that html nodes rendered correctly before we access it using javascript

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> 9.25 Excercise </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        //* <!-- Begin

        function calculate_prime(form) {
            var newWindow = window.open("","Test","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
            var doc = newWindow.document;
            doc.write("Prime: <br> <br>");

            var nstart = parseInt(form.startNum.value);
            var nend = parseInt(form.endNum.value);

            // give initial prime numbers, more is better
            var prime = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]; 

            // check with previous primes
            for(var z = prime[prime.length-1] + 2; z <= nend; z += 2) {
                var is_prime = true;
                // if current number divisible by previous primes
                for(var y = 1; y < prime.length; ++y) { 
                    // skip when divisor larger than half of z 
                    if(prime[y]>z/2) break; 
                    // if z divisible, then is not a prime
                    if(z%prime[y] == 0) { 
                        is_prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // if a prime, add it to our array
                if(is_prime) {
                    prime.push(z);
                }
            }

            // print all primes within the range
            for (var z = 0; z<prime.length; ++z) {
                if(prime[z] < nstart) continue;
                doc.write(prime[z] + ' ');
            }
        }
        // End --> */
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form name='form'>
        This Program finds Prime numbers and Palindromic numbers between two integers.<br>
        Maximum range between the integers is 999.<br>
        <hr />
        Starting Value (>0):  <input type="number" name="startNum" min="1" max="99999" value='1'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Ending Value (<= 99999): <input type="number" name="endNum" min="1" max="99999" value='99999'> <br>  <br>
        <input type=button value="Find Primes" onClick="calculate_prime(this.form)">
        <input type=button value="Find Palindromic Primes Only" onClick="calculate2(this.form)">
        <input type=button value="Find Both" onClick="calculate3(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just convert it to string, then reverse it.. see the link above on the first line of my answer..